How to fix -"No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element" when trying to hit swagger-ui/index.html endpoint
How to fix -"No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element" when trying to hit swagger-ui/index.html endpoint?
Adding below doesn't help:
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER

Expecting alternate solution for "No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element"
